# I want to extract 10 sheets from xlsx and export all the 10 sheets to csv format in python

Tags: python

I am able to extract the sheets from the xlsx file and transform those sheets in the csv format. However if i have many sheets lets say 40 sheets, then i am looking forward for a smarter way to extract the sheets. 
Below is the code which i worked.
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np

```
##Importing the Excel file
excelfile=pd.ExcelFile('single.xlsx')
# Reading all the individual sheet
sheet1=excelfile.parse('Sheet1')
sheet2=excelfile.parse('Sheet2')
sheet3=excelfile.parse('Sheet3')
sheet4=excelfile.parse('Sheet4')
sheet5=excelfile.parse('Sheet5')
sheet6=excelfile.parse('Sheet6')
sheet7=excelfile.parse('Sheet7')
sheet8=excelfile.parse('Sheet8')
sheet9=excelfile.parse('Sheet9')
sheet10=excelfile.parse('Sheet10')
#print(sheet2.head())

#exporting all the individual xlsx sheet to csv
sheet1.to_csv('sheet1.csv')
sheet2.to_csv('sheet2.csv')
sheet3.to_csv('sheet3.csv')
sheet4.to_csv('sheet4.csv')
sheet5.to_csv('sheet5.csv')
sheet6.to_csv('sheet6.csv')
sheet7.to_csv('sheet7.csv')
sheet8.to_csv('sheet8.csv')
sheet9.to_csv('sheet9.csv')
sheet10.to_csv('sheet10.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

Just loop on the sheet_names and generate your CSV names on the fly:

```py
excelfile = pd.ExcelFile('single.xlsx')
for i, name in enumerate(excelfile.sheet_names):
    sheet = excelfile.parse(name)
    csv_name = f'sheet_{i:02}.csv'
    sheet.to_csv(csv_name)
```